# AWS S3 images uploading issue with django and boto3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload image and load that uploaded images back to my webapp , previously loaded image in S3 bucket(which i uploaded manually) is rendering fine in the page but i am facing problem in uploading image in S3.

below is my settings.py config

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [


    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'storages',
]

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "given id"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "given secret key"
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = "young-minds-files"
AWS_S3_URL = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = "us-west-2"

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"
```

views.py

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ["title","content","image1","image2","image3"]
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Others')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image1 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    image2 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')
    image3 = models.ImageField(default='default_content.jpg', upload_to='content_pic')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

template

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<section class="site-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-4">
      <div class="col-md-6">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row blog-entries">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-8 main-content">

        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4"> Create Your Blog</legend>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>
    </section >
    <!-- END main-content -->

    {% endblock content %}
```

below is the error message when i try to upload an image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0U25.png)

error in console :

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://young-minds-california.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/content_pic/img_5.jpg"
```

Update :

I have resolved the issue , only problem was firewall which was in my network.

Comment: There is probably S3 bucket ACL or bucket policy issue. Could you please share the anonymized ACL and/or bucket policy? If you use the default setting, you will probably need to make it so that your IAM user is allowed to upload that object(in your case, the picture)

Comment: Could you suppress the AWS_S3_URL assignment and try again?

Comment: @congbaoguier I have resolved the issue , only problem was firewall which was in my network , thanks for taking time out to help!

Comment: Awesome! Firewall/security group is definitely the 1st thing you want to check when you have issue on AWS! ;)